# Get full ID searching with a selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a schedule made in a table. Each td has an id that start with "schedule" + dayofweek;
I mark when the schedule starts adding a class ".schedule_start".
I'm searching with a selector and i want to get the full id of the td's with the class "schedule_start"

here is my example:

```
for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    var tag1 = 'schedule-' + i + '-';
    if($("td[id ^='" + tag1 + "']").hasClass("schedule_start"))
    {
        console.log(tag1);
        // here i want to return the full id 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can instead do this:

```
$('td[id^=schedule].schedule_start').each(function() {
    console.log(this.id);
});
```

Comment: `$('td[id^=schedule].schedule_start')` - to filter the class right away.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    var tag1 = 'schedule-' + i + '-';
    var $tag = $("td[id ^='" + tag1 + "']");
    if($tag.hasClass("schedule_start"))
    {
        console.log($tag.attr("id");
        // here i want to return the full id 
    }
}
```